# Isomorphism in UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Is this statement true:

> Let $R$ be a **UFD** and $p,q\in R$ are irreducible which are not associated. Prove that for all $n,m\in\mathbb N$:
> $$R/(p^mq^n)\cong R/(p^m)\times R/(q^n).$$

I don't think that the chinese remainder theorem works here, however, it is easy to construct a map $f$ from $R$ to $R/(p^m)\times R/(q^n)$ with $\ker f=(p^mq^n)$. The only problem is to prove the map is onto.
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: It is the Chinese reminder theorem.

Comment: @JCAA why it works in here? the ideals $(p^m),(q^n)$ don't have to be co-prime

Comment: If you know example where these are not co-prime, you probably know a counterexample to your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JCAA probably gave the best answer to this question in comments.  However if you want further elaboration read on:

> Let $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$.  Then $R$ is a UFD, and $x,y$ are irreducible, and not associates.  If some element of $w\in R$ mapped to $(0,1)$ in $R/(x)\times R/(y)$ then $$w=ax=1+by$$ for some $a,b\in R$.  Then we would have $ax-by=1$, which is impossible as $(x),(y)$ are not coprime.

---

Edit:

The above just proves that your map is not an isomorphism.  To show that the rings are not isomorphic, note that $R/(x)\times R/(y)$ contains the idempotent $(1,0)$, which is non-trivial (not $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$).  To see that $R/(xy)$ has no such idempotent, note that elements of $R/(xy)$ may be uniquely written in the form $\alpha=c+xp(x)+yq(y)$, where $p,q$ are polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$.  Let $$\alpha^2=c'+xp'(x)+yq'(y),$$ for a constant $c'$ and polynomials $p',q'$.

Then if $\alpha^2=\alpha$ we have $\deg(q')=\deg(q)$, and $\deg(p')=\deg(p)$.  Thus $q=p=0$ and $\alpha=0$ or $1$.

Comment: But I think that those ring are ismoporphic. Aren’t they?

Comment: No, $R/(xy)$ is connected.  However good point (+1) - I only proved that your map is not an isomorphism, not that the rings are not isomorphic.

Comment: What is a ‘connected’ ring? I’m not sure that I know this definition

Comment: Other way round: connected means there is no non-trivial idempotent.  The product of the quotients has $(1,0)$ which is a non-trivial idempotent.  It is $R/(xy)$ which does not have any.  I will make an edit soon and let you know - just need to do a couple of things first.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it

Comment: Sorry for delay - is it clear now?

Comment: Perfect. I’ll tell you why I was sure this statement is right, it follows from the simple fact that I was required to **prove** (and I don’t mean a prove/disprove question) it on a test I had yesterday, Well I guess my professor meant PID instead of UFD...

Comment: More generally in any unital commutative ring $R$ with primes $p,q\in R$, if $(p^n), (q^n)$ are not coprime then $R/(p^nq^n)$ is connected, so finding $(p^n), (q^n)$ not coprime really was the key to the whole thing.  Proof: If $p^nq^n|\alpha(\alpha-1)$ then either $p,q|\alpha$ so $pq|\alpha^2=\alpha$ so $\alpha=0$ in $R/(p^nq^n)$, or $p,q|1-\alpha$ so $pq|(1-\alpha)^2=1-\alpha$ so $\alpha=1$ in $R/(p^nq^n)$.  Note you cannot have $p|\alpha, \,\, q|(1-\alpha)$ as $(p^n), (q^n)$ are not coprime.

Comment: The first sentence must be a joke. That user was clearly mistaken believing that CRT applies, and his/her second comment is just a philosophical remark.